# jQuery click event on ajax load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a basic table looking like:

```
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">userId</th>
            <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
            <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--Filled in with ajax-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript code: (data is loaded from database)

```
$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+userId+'</td><td>'+firstname+'</td><td>'+lastname+'</td><td class="details">Details</td></tr>')
```

Now when I click on Details, it should be called the click event:

```
$(".details").click(function () {
    console.log("test")
})
```

But nothing happen. What can it be? Is it because I am loading it with javascript?

Comment: You have to use event delegation `$(document).on('click', ".details", function ()`

Comment: Thx it works fine with your solution. Is there a reason why its not working with jquery?

Comment: When this code is loaded `$(".details").click(function () {` it bind the click event to every element with the class `details` but at that point your ajax haven't added `$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'` so they would not get the binding of the click event.